# Any insight on how to fix "XConnect Exception Filter OnException" errors?

Tags: xdb, solr, xconnect, indexing

Our instance has been pretty stable until recently we started receiving the following errors in XConnect.

*Main log*

```
[Error] XConnect Exception Filter OnException(), url - "https://site.com/odata/Contacts?%24filter=Identifiers%2fany(id:id%2fIdentifier+eq+'7qb86657e032442da64950e9f01d657'+and+id%2fSource+eq+'xDB.Tracker')&%24expand=Identifiers,MergeInfo,ConsentInformation,Classification,EngagementMeasures,ContactBehaviorProfile,Personal,KeyBehaviorCache,ListSubscriptions,AutomationPlanEnrollmentCache,AutomationPlanExit,TestCombinations"
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

*Indexworker log*

```
[Error] An error occured.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 503 ({metadata={error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException,root-error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException},msg=SolrCore is loading,code=503}).
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrClient.<SendGetRequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrRebuildStatusStorage.<ReadStatus>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerHost.<RunRebuildStatusWatcher>d__28.MoveNext()
```

WE restarted the Solr service and attempted to rebuild the xDB index with no success. We are running Sitecore 9.0.2 with Solr 6.6.3

Has anyone experienced this issue before and found a solution?

Comment: Is that first log from xConnect or Sitecore?

Comment: The log is from xConnect.